# Bottom Navigation View in Support Library v25.0.0 animation?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

> Reference: Nick Butcher's Tweet
>   https://twitter.com/crafty/status/789008273949200384

I implemented **Bottom Navigation View** came out with `Android Support Library v25.0.0`.

https://github.com/vipulasri/Bottom-Navigation-View-Sample

I am facing following problems:

1. `Floating Action Button` overlaps with `Bottom Navigation View`.
2. `Snackbar` displays above `Bottom Navigation View`.
3. Bottom Navigation Button doesn't automatically hide or appear on  scrolling.
4. Not able to get the *reveal animation* like below:

[image: Bottom Navigation View Animation]

Comment: 3. In my case, the bottom bar hides on scroll, but when scrolling up instead of down, lol. 4. the reveal animation works, but it doesn't change the whole background, it just transitions the icon and does alpha on the text.

Comment: I have the same problems, did you manage to find solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

About your third and fourth question. Bottom navigation view is automatically hide title and make animation **if you have more then 3** item in it.

And about you first and second question. You can try another root layout, for example [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late, but I made a little project to make reveal animation on background like your example without third part library.

Check it here: `https://github.com/GauvainSeigneur/CircularRevealBottomNavigationView`

Comment: When posting answers, please include a description of what you did in your text rather than just posting a link to a solution.